# Make tools indestructible in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, is there any way to make tools indestructible (without using mods)? I want to make some tools indestructible (for an adventure map). Is it possible to do this using enchantments (or a command of some kind?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest you can get to that is enchanting your tools to make them last longer, increasing the uses significantly.

Another option for an adventure map would be to provide anvils through the map and hide raw materials that you could use to repair your tools.

Comment: +1. Slap Unbreaking X on it and for all intents and purposes it'll be indestructible. Well, unless it's incinerated.

Comment: @lunboks Is it really possible to give an item infinite durability using the "Unbreaking X" enchantment? If so, how?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Well, no. It'll just last a very, very long time. Unbreaking I is double durability, II is triple, III is quadruple, etc. If we're talking about a wooden tool, you could also crank up the enchantment level to Unbreaking C. That should be long enough for everyone.

Comment: @lunboks I've pulverized through unbreaking 100 on diamond tools on prison servers... just saying

Answer (score 41):

You can use "Unbreakable" NBT tag to make your items unbreakable. Example with a sword:

`/give @a minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}`

Comment: This is exactly what the Unbreakable tag is for. One of these should become the accepted answer (or voted up).

Answer (score 16):

Items in Minecraft have a *Damage* value attached to them. For tools this is used to determine how much the item is damaged. For example, diamond tools break when this number reaches 1562 (their [durability](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Durability#Tool_durability)).

By casting an *Unbreaking III* [enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Tool_Enchantments) on the tool (`/enchant playername 24 3`) you make it last 4 times as long: *1562·(1+3) =* **6248** uses on average. The game doesn't let you enchant for a higher level.

If that's not enough for you, you will have to use an external game data editing program.
Note that the program is only needed once. No mods will be required afterwards, neither for you, nor for the players of your map.

At first, make sure you have the desired tool (with *Unbreaking* already) in your Minecraft inventory, then close the world.
Now is a good time to make a backup of your world in case something goes wrong.

Let's use [**NBTEdit**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/) to edit the information about the tool.

- **Open** the **level.dat** file inside your world's directory.
- Go to **Data** → **Player** → **Inventory**.
- Select the entry which has the [**id**](http://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com/) of your tool (for example, a diamond pickaxe is **278**).
- Double-click on **Damage** and change the value to **-32768** (*-2^15*, the smallest number `short int` data type can hold).
- Open the item's **tag** → **ench** → "**2 entries**" and change the **lvl** to 10. (You can make the level even larger, but it won't look good in the game: "*Unbreaking X*" vs "*Unbreaking enchantment.level.11*").
- **Save** the file.

Now you have an item with *(32768+1562)·(1+10) =* **377630** uses. Moreover, for the first 360448 uses (i.e. forever) the item won't have its damage bar displayed. Also, the tool doesn't even have to be diamond: a wooden tool will still have *(32768+60)·(1+10) =* **361108** uses.

Comment: This does work, and the minimum damage value is -32768.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this command (in a command bock). Copy as so into game anything in the `()`.  It's your choice in what you want to put. Note I did this in 1.7.2:

`/give @p diamond_sword {Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:(enchantment id),lvl:(enchantment power),display:{Name:"(name of item)",Lore:["(a little msg about anything)"]}}`

You can extend things like the total enchants and lines of Lore some examples
multiple enchants: `ench:[{id:(enchantment id),lvl:(enchantment power)},{id:(enchantment id),lvl:(enchantment power)},{` and so on.

More lore lines: `Lore:["(a little msg about anything)","Lore:["(a little msg about anything)","` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
/give @a minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

Completely works. I tested it with a  gold sword in 1.8.1 and it never lost any durability.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested and need an indestructible item for Minecraft 1.2.5 and/or maybe for some Minecraft with SPC installed, try this: `/item "number item" 1 -3000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use command blocks: lets say 247 is a wooden sword (247 is not really a wooden sword, just an example), so do:

`give [playername or @p or something] [item ID] [amount] [191918]`

so it should look something like that:

`give @p 247 1 191918`

That will give you an indestructible sword!

Comment: Why use a command block instead of just a command? Why use exactly "191918"?