# How do you make items unbreakable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really want to know how to do that

Comment: If you are on education edition, which I highly doubt that you are but just want to put this out there for anybody using education edition, use /worldimmutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:

`/give @p minecraft:stick{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreaking",lvl:2147483647}]} 1`

Also change stick for your item of choice.

Comment: I am not Minecraft Command expert, but what exactly will adding Sharpness do to make an item unbreakable?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method is to use cheat

```
/give @p minecraft:YOURITEM 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

Comment: Also it is a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95711/make-tools-indestructible-in-minecraft'this